# Side Navigation Bar not showing on click of Navigation drawer Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get a navigation drawer working which is similar to http://bdinfosys.com/demo/materialx/ using bootstrap. I have a main navigation bar and I have been able to get a navigation drawer for mobile screens. I have created a sidebar which is hidden by default. On clicking the drawer I want my side navigation bar to appear and the contents of main navigation bar to be not present. However currently when I click the drawer, my side navigation is not shown and all the options of my main navigation bar are still present.

My HTML page source:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="primary-nav">
        <div class="container"> <a href="#" class="navbar-brand hidden-xs">MyName</a>

            <button id="menu-toggle" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">    

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT ME<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">RESUME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">BLOG</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="mobile_sideNav">
        <div class="row profile">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="profile-sidebar">
                    <!-- SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
                    <div class="profile-userpic">
                        <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/admin/pages/media/profile/profile_user.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <!-- END SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
                    <!-- SIDEBAR USER TITLE -->
                    <div class="profile-usertitle">
                        <div class="profile-usertitle-name">
                            Marcus Doe
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile-usertitle-job">
                            Developer
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END SIDEBAR USER TITLE -->
                    <!-- SIDEBAR BUTTONS -->
                    <div class="profile-userbuttons">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Follow</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Message</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END SIDEBAR BUTTONS -->
                    <!-- SIDEBAR MENU -->
                    <div class="profile-usermenu">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                                Overview </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                                Account Settings </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                Tasks </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i>
                                Help </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END MENU -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="profile-content">
                   Some user related content goes here...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My Javascript Source:

```
function detectmob() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mobile_sideNav").hide();
    if(detectmob()) {
        $("#primary-nav").hide();
    }
});

$("#menu-toggle").click( function() {
    $("#mobile_sideNav").show();
});
```

My css:

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }

  html,  div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.brand-bg, .sweet-alert button {
  background-color: #00bcd4 !important;
}

.projects-wrap {
  padding: 110px 0;
}  
.root-sec {
  position: relative;
}

.main-section {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}


/* Profile container */
.profile {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

/* Profile sidebar */
.profile-sidebar {
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.profile-userpic img {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.profile-usertitle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.profile-usertitle-name {
  color: #5a7391;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.profile-usertitle-job {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #5b9bd1;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.profile-userbuttons {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.profile-userbuttons .btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.profile-userbuttons .btn:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.profile-usermenu {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f4f7;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li a {
  color: #93a3b5;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li a i {
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #fafcfd;
  color: #5b9bd1;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li.active a {
  color: #5b9bd1;
  background-color: #f6f9fb;
  border-left: 2px solid #5b9bd1;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

/* Profile Content */
.profile-content {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 460px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I think the way I am detecting if its a mobile screen or not is not the best way to go about this as I am testing on a desktop browser. Probably a better way to do is to check the screen size

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the position to fixed and then animating the css to slide into view. Something like this : http://daviddataram.com/Portfolio_Sites/combatStress/index.html. 
By setting the size and position in css, when a user clicks the icon, use jquery to slide the menu onto the screen:

```
$('#wrapper').click(function(){
$('#wrapper').css('direction of screen' , 'width of wrapper')
}
```